# Количество процессов

Tags: linux

Я правильно понимаю, что в коде ниже создается 2 процесса? Так как один вызов fork() создает один поток. В коде два таких вызова, следовательно, процесса создается 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int x,y;
    pid_t pidl, pid2;

    x = 2;
    y = 3;

    printf ("Single process, x=$d\n",x);
    pidl = fork();
    if(pidl == 0) {
      printf ("New, x=%d\n",x);
      exit (0);
    }
    if(pid1 < 0){
       printf("Cannot create");
       exit (1);
    }
    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2 == 0) {
       printf ("New, y=%d\n",y);
       exit (0);
    }
    if(pid2 < 0){
      printf("Cannot create");
      exit (1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не используйте изображения, для демонстрации кода. Оно маленькое и низкого качества, ничего не видно. Добавьте код в тело вопроса с соответствующим форматом

Comment: Ну похоже, только создаются они цепочкой, то есть дед-отец-ребёнок.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо. То есть, 3 правильный ответ?

Comment: Что вам даст правильный ответ, если нет видения всей картины? При запуске этого кода в ОС могут появиться на какой-то момент три процесса.